# How to open very large XML files?

Tags: xml

I am trying to open a XML file that is over 50 gb. I have tried many different XML file viewers but the file is always to large for them. Are there any easy to use XML viewers that can open this big of a file?

Comment: If you had a window showing 50gb file, what would you actually do with it?  Its too big to navigate in any meaningful way ...

Comment: There are text editors out there that can deal with big files; e.g. HiEditor.  Personally when faced with a large XML file, rather than trying to read the whole thing I use scripts to interrogate it / show the bits I'm interested in; rather than trying to open the entire thing in one go.

Comment: NB: This sort of question's unlikely to get an answer on this site; you're better asking on Software Recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This solution may help; recommended for JSON, but the comments mention it handles XML and the pro version works for large files.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/47983/5002  I've no personal experience, so can't comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, fundamentally, *two* available ways to manage an XML file, and the second one applies in your case:

- Reading the entire XML file into memory to create a corresponding data structure.
- Parsing the file's content in place, calling specified subroutines when specified elements are found as the logic "walks through" the file.

*(In some cases, relational databases are used to locate the offset within the file of interesting bits of information, the location of recent search-results, and so on. "File walkers" often have the ability to reposition to a certain byte-offset to begin their search from there.)*

XML file viewers also use one of the other approaches, the first being the most common.  But I'm sure that you *can* find a viewer that is designed specifically for huge files.

You provide absolutely no information as to what language you are using, your environment, *etc,* so I cannot further speculate. But, this is the general lay of the land.

In the Perl language, for instance, two contenders might be `XML::LibXML` *(first approach),* and `XML::Twig` *(second).*

Answer (score 1):

What do you actually want to do with the file?

If you want to view a sample of the file on screen, try the "more" command (though it may struggle if there are no newlines).

If you want, for example, to extract a subset of the file, or do some aggregation such as computing totals and averages, then consider an XSLT 3.0 streaming transformation.